# check if is an array for each value

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have three input boxes:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="1">
   <input type="text" name="2">
   <input type="text" name="3">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

When the user clicks submit, I would like to check if the inputted value appears in an array only if their filled in.

For example if the first two were filled in, I would check if the inputted value appears in the array **and not** the last one (as it wasn't filled in!).

I have this code all so far:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'] {
   $array = array('432423', '434', '3', '2', '213');
   // rest of code to check each input
}
?>
```

I think i need `in_array`

Comment: array_serach('432423',$array);

Comment: yes but how do i do it for each input only if theyre not empty

Comment: use foreach($_POST as $row) { if(!empty($row)) { array_serach($row,$array);  } }

Comment: how does that use the if statement?

Comment: check out my edited comment

Comment: hello again. but that checks if the submit button has an array value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117921/discussion-between-jothi-and-bob-jomes).

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array()`

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'] {

   $array = array('432423', '434', '3', '2', '213');

   $success = true;

   foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (!empty($value) && $key != "submit") {
            if (!in_array($value, $array)) {
                $success = false;
            }
        }
   }


   var_dump($success); 
   // TRUE if all contains, FLASE if any one doesn't contain

}

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503970/check-if-is-an-array-for-each-value#comment64412843_38504931

Comment: Hello what if I wanted a certain input box not to have to match the array?

Comment: For that use in_array($_POST['1'], $array) ... Here, 1 is the name attribute of input box